# Rabbitmq-c Library: How to get 'method' returned by the broker

Tags: c, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using the rabbitmq-c library to connect to a RabbitMQ server (GNU/Linux build environment).

At one point when I use "**amqp_channel_open(...)**", I'm getting an error from the server which I want to debug.

I call "**amqp_get_rpc_reply(...)**" as per the examples. It returns an **amqp_rpc_reply_t** which I assign to a variable "my_reply".

**my_reply.reply_type** is AMQP_RESPONSE_SERVER_EXCEPTION, which is why I think it's an error from the server.

HOWEVER, [here are the docs](http://alanxz.github.io/rabbitmq-c/docs/0.2/structamqp__rpc__reply__t.html#a32ecf019bce08d80222bca5f927d96b8) for the **amqp_rpc_reply_t** type.

For my_reply.reply: "in case of AMQP_RESPONSE_SERVER_EXCEPTION this field will be set to the method returned from the broker"

So my_reply.reply is an **amqp_method_t** in this case. But when I look at the docs for amqp_method_t, it has two fields: **id** ("the method id number", ??) and **decoded**.

For **decoded**, it's a **void ***:
 "pointer to the decoded method, cast to the appropriate type to use"

I am stuck at this point, because I have no idea what to cast **decoded* to. It should be some kind of data structure containing the information returned by the server (the AMQP method), but I can't find any reference to what type I should cast it to.

[Edited for clarity]

Answer (score 2):

I dug around a bit in the examples, and found something helpful.

When my_reply.reply_type is **AMQP_RESPONSE_SERVER_EXCEPTION**, the field my_reply.reply.id contains one of the **AMQP_xxxxxx_METHOD** constants which are defined by macros in **amqp_framing.h** - [see here and scroll down a bit](http://alanxz.github.io/rabbitmq-c/docs/0.2/amqp__framing_8h.html#a0316f5796e2632b49ceebb58e2644b48).

Each of these method IDs has an associated type which follows the same naming convention - e.g. for **AMQP_CONNECTION_CLOSE_METHOD** (which I was getting) there is **amqp_connection_close_t**. [See here for a list of data structures / types](http://alanxz.github.io/rabbitmq-c/docs/0.5.0/classes.html).

Knowing which type to cast **my_reply.reply.decoded** to, it's pretty easy to then extract the useful information - e.g. (from examples, assuming my_reply.reply.id is AMQP_CONNECTION_CLOSE_METHOD):

```
amqp_connection_close_t *m = (amqp_connection_close_t *)my_reply.reply.decoded;
printf( "Server connection error %d, message: %.*s\n",
               m->reply_code,
         (int) m->reply_text.len,
      (char *) m->reply_text.bytes);
```